# Scrollable sticky div alongside container

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been having issues keeping a sticky div that contains text which is rotated 90 deg inside an adjacent container. I am trying to accomplish what is in the image below.

[image: img of sticky top of container]

The issue is that I've tried to align it correctly to stay within the container and scroll correctly but the sticky div which contains text, flows out of its container. 
See the image below.

[image: img of sticky flowing out of container]

```
/* This is the css*/    
.work-section {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.work-title {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 370px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width: fit-content;
    left: 80px;
    transform-origin: 0 0 0px;
}

.tt {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
}

.test-img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the JSfiddle:
[https://jsfiddle.net/Ratsuns/mz08oew3/17/](https://jsfiddle.net/Ratsuns/mz08oew3/13/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made three variants, with some sort results. Every has it's ideas and restrictions.

**First**, modified [Ryan Nghiem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59821874/7546986)

Main difference - made `tt class` auto square, and moved heading to text left.
Main restriction - heading doesn't go belower bottom edge of container.

```css
body {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: black !important;
}

/* Work Section */

.work-section {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.abs-work {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: -1%;
}
.work-title {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: fit-content;
}

.tt {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.test-img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-abs.css">

</head>

<body>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Random-Code</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <section>
            <div style="height: 150px"></div>
        </section>
        <section id="work-section1">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="abs-work">
                    <div class="work-title">
                        <div class="tt">
                            <h2>Recent Work</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">

                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <div style="height: 1800px"></div>
        </section>
    </body>
    <!-- Scripts Jquery Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js "
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js "
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6 "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>

    </html>


    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Second variant,** used `display: flex`. Heading goes belower bottom edge of container.

Main restriction - `<div>` with heading has width, that matters, and it is wider with longer heading.

```css
body {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: black !important;
  }
  
  /* Work Section */
  
  .container {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
  }
  
  .work-section {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .work-title {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 90% 90%;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .tt {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  
  .test-img {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-flex.css">

</head>

<body>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Random-Code</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <section>
            <div style="height: 150px"></div>
        </section>
        <section id="work-section1">
            <div class="container">
                <div>
                    <div class="work-title">
                        <div class="tt">
                            <h2>Recent Work</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">

                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <div style="height: 1800px"></div>
        </section>
    </body>
    <!-- Scripts Jquery Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js "
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js "
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6 "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>

    </html>


    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Third variant,** ridiculous, just for ideas.

```css
body {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: black !important;
  }
  
  /* Work Section */
  
  .container {
      display: flex;
  }
  
  .work-section {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .test-img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .lala2 {
      display: flex;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      height: fit-content;
  }

  .lala {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: 8px;
  }

  .lala div {
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      font-size: 2rem;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .lala div span {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Random-Code</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <section>
            <div style="height: 150px"></div>
        </section>
        <section id="work-section1">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="lala2">
                    <div class="lala">
                        <div><span>R</span></div>
                        <div><span>e</span></div>
                        <div><span>c</span></div>
                        <div><span>e</span></div>
                        <div><span>n</span></div>
                        <div><span>t</span></div>
                        <div><span>&#8199</span></div>
                        <div><span>W</span></div>
                        <div><span>o</span></div>
                        <div><span>r</span></div>
                        <div><span>k</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">

                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row work-section">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Tuml</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi exercitationem, aperiam
                                nisi
                                dolor harum corrupti necessitatibus dolore dolores nesciunt voluptate iste nobis amet
                                omnis
                                deserunt minima officiis, facere quisquam eius
                                fugiat. Recusandae at molestiae voluptate quasi aliquid? Mollitia animi, dolore fuga
                                impedit
                                rerum ratione minus quas enim natus aperiam nihil!
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-self-end">Dark</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img class="test-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/rH7c4mM/9000.gif" alt="9000" border="0">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <div style="height: 1800px"></div>
        </section>
    </body>
    <!-- Scripts Jquery Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js "
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js "
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6 "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>

    </html>


    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @aleksandr! Your first modified solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a parent div with `position: absolute;` full height of `container` div.

Let's see my code:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.abs-work {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.work-title {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  left: 80px;
  transform-origin: 0, 0, 0px;
}
```

`.work-title` must to be a square when you using `transform: rotate(-90deg);`

This is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ryannghiem/c8p60ea4/13/)

Comment: Almost what I was looking for. I think @AleksandrBelugin used your solution and modified it to work properly in his examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
.work-title {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 100px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: -120px;
  transform-origin: 0, 0, 0px;
}
```

Comment: You can play with the div's margin and top to adjust the div according to your requirement.